# Primefaces lazyDataModel filter not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

У меня есть две таблицы stock и product. Таблицу я инициализирую через stock, но фильтр мне нужно сделать через product.

JSF:

```
<p:dataTable id="stockTable" value="#{stockPage.stocks}" var="stock" style="margin-top: 20px;" paginator="true" 
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="20,100,200,500" rows="20" lazy="true" rowIndexVar = "row" emptyMessage="Ничего не найдено" reflow="true">

                <p:column headerText="Название продукта" filterBy="#{stock.product.name}">
                    #{stock.product.name}
                </p:column>
```

Это фильтр , но он не правильно работает:

```
/*
 * For Lazy
 */
public int countStock(Category category, Integer storeId, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<Stock> stock = cq.from(Stock.class);

    Predicate filterCondition = getFilterCondition(cb, stock, filters);
    if (category != null) {
        filterCondition = cb.and(filterCondition, cb.equal(stock.get("product").get("categoryId"), category.getId()));
    }
    filterCondition = cb.and(filterCondition, cb.equal(stock.get("storeId"), storeId));
    cq.where(filterCondition);

    cq.select(cb.count(stock));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult().intValue();
}

// For lazy load datatable
private Predicate getFilterCondition(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Stock> stock, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    Predicate filterCondition = cb.conjunction();
    String wildCard = "%";
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> filter : filters.entrySet()) {
        try {
            final String value = (String) filter.getValue();
            if (!value.equals("")) {
                Path<String> path = stock.get(filter.getKey()); // ошибка здесь!!!
                if (AbstractProduct.class.getDeclaredField(filter.getKey()).getType().equals(String.class)) {
                    String likeValue = wildCard + value + wildCard;
                    filterCondition = cb.and(filterCondition, cb.like(path, likeValue));
                } else if (AbstractProduct.class.getDeclaredField(filter.getKey()).getType().equals(Integer.class)
                        || AbstractProduct.class.getDeclaredField(filter.getKey()).getType().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
                    try {
                        filterCondition = cb.and(filterCondition, cb.equal(path, new Integer(value)));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    filterCondition = cb.and(filterCondition, cb.equal(path, filter.getValue()));
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
    return filterCondition;
}
```

я думаю , нужно как-то через JOIN все это сделать , но точно не понимаю как , кто знает , подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Переведите пожалуйста название вопроса на Русский.

Answer (score 0):

**Primefaces lazyDataModel filter working**

В зависимости от значения ключа в фильтре есть несколько вариантов.
Один универсальный. Предполагая, что ключ равен `"name"`:

```
Path<String> path;
if ("name".equals(filter.getKey()) {
   path = stock.get("product").get("name"); 
} else {
   path = stock.get(filter.getKey());
}
```

Если ключ равен `"product.name"`, то можно подставить вместо `"name"` выше, или пойти другим путём. Для начала создать метод, получающий "вложенный" путь, потому что `javax.persistence.criteria.Path.get()` сам не разбирает пути.

```
private static Path getPath(Path p, String s) {
    for (String a : s.split("\\.")) {
        p = p.get(a);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Теперь применяем этот метод вместо `stock.get(filter.getKey())`

```
Path<String> path = getPath(stock, filter.getKey());
```

Что для `"product.name"` эквивалентно `Path<String> path = stock.get("product").get("name");`.

Я не помню какой ключ так на самом деле. Вы можете узнать это с помощью отладки, напечатать в консоль или вывести на страницу. По результатам расследования воспользоваться тем или иным вариантом.